# fit GLM for weibull family

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, survival, gamlss

I am trying to fit generalized linear model for weibull family, but when I try it in R, it gives an error. I know that weibull does not fit in exponential family, but I have read some research articles about fitting GLM for weibull family. If anyone can help me with this, I really appreciate. 
It gives the following error.

```
> data(lung)
> glm(time ~ age+sex+ph.ecog+ wt.loss, family = weibull(link='log'), data = lung)
Error in glm(time ~ age + sex + ph.ecog + wt.loss, family = weibull(link = "log"),  : 
  could not find function "weibull"
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry i'm quite late with this.... but might help someone i believe :

`gamlss` package is what you should be looking for. It supports almost all the distributions( not just exponential family ones). It gives amazing flexibility on almost all the parameters of a distribution.

Comment: +1. `gamlss` supports the Weibull distribution via `WEI`, `WEI2` and `WEI3`, all 2-parameter though obviously different. Not sure if it supports censoring, though, which would be a key element of an AFT survival model.

Comment: @Wayne gamlss definitely supports right censoring and left truncation also ....both also if wanted

Answer (score 3):

The `glm()` function does not support the Weibull distribution in R unfortunately. You can try `?family` to see which distributions are available. I would try using `survreg()` from the `survival` package instead.

Comment: yeah glm() do not support weibull. I am trying to use glm approach and AFT model using survreg, then compare the results of two methods. That is why I tried to figure it out to fit glm for weibull. Thank you for your comments. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `brms` package, which is Bayesian. It supports the Weibull, exponential, lognormal, Frechet, and other families and (left/right/interval) censoring so implements AFT models. It also includes random effects which are known in survival models as "frailty", and a host of other regression options like gam-style smoothers.

Since Bayesian approaches use MCMC sampling, it's slower than `glm`, `gamlss`, or `survreg`, but it's also a comprehensive regression solution, and being Bayesian has other advantages. (I love it's `stanplot`, which provides a host of illuminating diagnostic plots.)