# How to compare indvidual Weibull parrmetres (i.e. shape and scale) between different distributions using R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, weibull-distribution

I know you can compare Weibull distributions using the likelihood test but I was asking if there is a way to compare individual parameters like (shape and scale) between different distributions. A similar process is provided by [Minitab](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/20/help-and-how-to/statistical-modeling/reliability/how-to/parametric-distribution-analysis-right-censoring/interpret-the-results/equality-of-parameters/) I'd like to know if such approach is possible using R.
A similar question was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348199/compare-shape-and-scale-parameters-between-weibull-distributions) but again the answer was talking about comparing the distribution as whole.
I use the following code for comparing distributions:

```
library(MASS)  
compare_weibull <- function(x, y) {
    pooled <- fitdistr(x = c(x, y), densfun = "weibull")
    pooled <- pooled$log
    A <- fitdistr(x = x, densfun = "weibull")
    A <- A$log
    B <- MASS::fitdistr(x = y, densfun = "weibull")
    B <- B$log
    p <- pchisq(2 * ((A + B) - pooled), df = 2, lower.tail = FALSE)
    data.frame(stat = 2 * ((A + B) - pooled), p = p)
  }
```

Thanks in advance.